On coproducts of presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories
Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories, i.e., symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories whose underlying $\infty$-category are presentable and whose tensor products distribute over small colimits. By regarding them as commutative algebra objects in $\mathcal{P}\mathrm{r}^L$, the $\infty$-category of presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories and left adjoints, we obtain another presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$  by tensoring the commutative algebras.
Now the tensor products of commutative algebras is a coproduct in the category of commutative algebras, so for every presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$, the map
$$\theta:\operatorname{Fun}^{\otimes ,L}(\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C})\to \operatorname{Fun}^{\otimes ,L}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{C})\times \operatorname{Fun}^{\otimes ,L}(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})$$
induces a homotopy equivalence between the maximal sub $\infty$-groupoids. Here
$\operatorname{Fun}^{\otimes,L}(-,-)$ denotes the $\infty$-category of symmetric monoidal functors whose underlying functors preserve small colimits. My question is:
Is $\theta$ a categorical equiavlence? If so, how can one prove this?
I see this being stated without proof in various literature, but I do not know how I can justify this. Thanks in advance!
P.S.
I prefer an answer that does not use too much of ($\infty,2$)-category theory because I am not familiar with them, but if that's inevitable I will try to get my hands on it.

There is a common trick to "talk about 2-categories without 2-categories": it suffices to check that, for every small simplicial set $K$, applying $\operatorname{Hom}(K,-)$, you get an equivalence of anima, and if I am not mistaken, this reduces to the case of replacing $\mathcal C$ by $\operatorname{Fun}(K,\mathcal C)$.

To be clear, the key point that you need for Z. M argument to work is that $Hom(K,Fun^{\otimes,L}(A,C) ) \simeq Fun^{\otimes,L}(A, Hom(K,C) )$, where $Hom(K,C)$ has the levelwise monoidal structure. This is definitely correct. But I'm not sure it is proved anywhere in the litterature,

@Z.M Of course! (I thought about applying $\operatorname{Hom}(K,-)$, but I was somehow stuck at tensoring the first argument and never thought about powering the second argument.) Thank you very much for your comment. If you can turn your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it.
